# Setting width and height of fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, width

I've tried the following code with little to no avail:

```
    $(document).ready(function(e){
        $(".iframe").fancybox(
                {
                    height: 950,
                    width: 400                        }
        );
    });
```

I've put everything in quotes and everything without quotes and nothing seems to have any effect of the fancybox. There does seem to be some effect on the width, but it's irregular and temperamental. From what I can tell, all including the width does it set the width to it's default value.

Comment: can you show the html code of the .iframe class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".iframe").fancybox({
       maxWidth  : 950,
       maxHeight : 400,
       fitToView : false,
       width     : '100%',
       height    : '100%',
       autoSize  : false
    });
});
```